# Google App Engine nodejs website error 503

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

We are deploying a nodejs application in gcloud using

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
```

but every time it is deployed and the link is followed the following error is displayed:

```
Error: Server Error
The service you requested is not available yet.

Please try again in 30 seconds
```

However, in 30 seconds, or days later, the error is still there.
All the vm's are healthy according to app engine console. and no obvious errors are appearing in the logs.

Can someone please help as to where we can start looking for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably deploying a Node.js Managed VM. I would start by deploying with the parameter --verbosity debug to see if there is interesting information that points you to why it is failing. If that doesn't work, you can access the Managed VM to see what happens by changing it to user managed[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/access#changing_management) and ssh-ing into it.